# Using 'hacks' in programming?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this example pseudo-code that works, $x basically is an object with keys and values or array with keys and objects as values. $y will be constructed in two different ways.

```
private function someFunction($x) {
    if (is_object($x)) {
        $y = 'result of something';
    } elseif (is_array($x)) {
        $y = 'result of something';
    } else {
        $y = null;
    }

    return $y;
}
```

Is this a good practice, if function will not be used anywhere else? 'Non-hack' way probably is to convert object to an array (because it is an array in essence) and then make logic based on count of arrays.

Or am I just thinking to much about writing code 'right way'?

Comment: It's actually pretty bad practice.  Why not just always construct the data structure you're processing in this function the same way?  If you have code like this it's usually an indication of something wrong with the design.

Comment: I'm split on this one.  Ideally, as @GordonM says, you should have data constructed in the same manner always - you can still check for `is_object` to deal with non-initialised input properly, however if you don't control the input, then I don't see why this would be a bad idea.

Comment: I'd  be broadly OK with this, especially if it's some kind of library/utility function, and "what it does" is something you might sensibly want to do to both sorts of input.  In essence, the `is_XXX()` checks are the same checks as other languages use to decide which version of an overloaded function to call: e.g. `int myfunc( int param )` vs. `int myfunc( string param )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of using this function is acceptable as long as the input is controlled by you and you know what you are going to do with the data. However on inputs from uncontrolled sources from outside, you should validate the data beforehand as you would not know for sure if the data is valid.

What I don't understand is how you reach a point a variable may be two different types: an array or an object.

If you convert it to array and then process it, or use your own function, the important thing is that your logic flows and the code does what it is intended to do.

**If context is right and the code does what it is intended to do, then your code is just fine.**

Answer (score 2):

In PHP this is actually the only way this is possible and I wouldn't call it bad practice in itself at least for type checking. In Java and other languages we have method overloading:

```
public String someFunction(Object $x) {
    return "Result of something";
}

public String someFunction(Object[] $x) {
    return "Result of something";
}

public String someFunction(int $y) {
    return "Result of something";
}
```

In PHP, I'd suggest a similar separation of concerns like so:

```
private function someFunction($x) {
    if (is_object($x)) {
        $y = $this->someFunctionObject($x);
    } elseif (is_array($x)) {
        $y = $this->someFunctionArray($x);
    } else {
        $y = $this->someFunctionScalar($x);
    }

    return $y;
}


private function someFunctionObject($x) {

}

private function someFunctionArray($x) { 

}

private function someFuctionScalar($x) {

}
```

The problem with a loosely typed language such as PHP is that there are actually types and sometimes you need to deal with them.

I'd argue that having to do a conversion every time someFunction is called is worse than doing the type check and conversion internally because repeated code is going to be more problematic than an if/else in one method.

Comment: @ponciste: A lot depends how complicated the bits of code are.  For simpler cases, where you're doing "almost the same thing" for all input types, the overhead of having three separate functions might make things harder to follow.  As the "thing being done" gets more complicated, or as the behaviour for different types of input move further apart from each other, then having one  dispatcher and three separate functions makes it easier to see the "wood" (what to do for a particular type) from the "trees" (telling the differnet types apart; doing the type-invariant parts).